# Replacing a value in the dictionary by another from a string by looking at the variation with an old string

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an old string and a modified one. Then also values from old string in dictionary format. I am trying to check if the values in dictionary is still present as such in new string. If yes nothing happens. If there is a change in the value, the value in the dictionary is replace by the modified value. If the value in dictionary is not present in new string, then update the value in dictionary by `None`.

**Code**

```
import re

db_tag_old = {"art":"art", "organizer":"james", "month":"December", "season":"summer"}

old = 'The art is performed by james. _______ Season is summer _____ time. It is December.'
new = 'The art is performed by ______ Mathew. Season is ______ autmn time. __ __ _________'

db_tag_new = {}
final_db_tag = {}

symbol = '_'
needle = f'{re.escape(symbol)}+'
position = [(match.start(),match.end()) for match in re.finditer(needle, old)]

for key,value in db_tag_old.items():   
    position_old = [(match.start(),match.end()) for match in re.finditer(value.lower(), old)]
    position_new = [(match.start(),match.end()) for match in re.finditer(value.lower(), new)]
    if position_old == position_new and [] not in (position_old, position_new)::
        db_tag_new.update({key:value})
        continue
    else:
        new_value = new[position[0][0]:position[0][1]]
        db_tag_new.update({key:new_value})
final_db_tag.update({"old":db_tag_old,"new":db_tag_new})
print(final_db_tag)
```

**Output Obtained**

```
{'old': {'art': 'art', 'organizer': 'james', 'month': 'December', 'season': 'summer'}, 'new': {'art': 'art', 'organizer': 'Mathew.', 'month': 'Mathew.', 'season': 'Mathew.'}}
```

Here in the dictionary key `"new"`, month and season are wring values.

**Expected Output**

```
{'old': {'art': 'art', 'organizer': 'james', 'month': 'December', 'season': 'summer'}, 'new': {'art': 'art', 'organizer': 'Mathew.', 'month': 'None', 'season': 'autmn'}}
```

How this can be corrected

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear to me, what the rule is to replace old with new text. The following code produces the wanted result, but I'm not sure whether this approach is as universal as needed:

```
import re

db_tag_old = {"art":"art", "organizer":"james.", "month":"December", "season":"summer"}

old = 'The art is performed by james. _______ Season is summer _____ time. It is December.'
new = 'The art is performed by ______ Mathew. Season is ______ autmn time. __ __ _________'

db_tag_new = {}
# pre-definition for dict-entries we won't find:
for key, val in db_tag_old.items():
    db_tag_new[key] = "None"
    
owords = old.split();
nwords = new.split();

for (i, nw) in enumerate(nwords):
    # the "art"-case:
    for key, ow in db_tag_old.items():
        if nw == ow:
            db_tag_new[key] = ow

    # "organizer" / "season" cases:
    if re.match(r'^_+$', nw):
        for key, ow in db_tag_old.items():
            if ow == owords[i] and re.match(r'^_+$', owords[i+1]):
                db_tag_new[key] = nwords[i+1]

print("old: ", db_tag_old)
print("new: ", db_tag_new)
```

Comment: Thanks. This might work. I need to check and will accept the answer. Thanks for your attempt. Please upvote the question too.